# How to use Binder.GetIndex

Tags: c#, dynamic, binding, runtime

I was trying to find the answer using search but finally decided to create new question instead.

I'm working on XML serialization into dynamic types, I did everything but now I want to be able to access members in a way similar to reflection.

In my type that is inherited from `DynamicObject`, I implemented `TryGetMemeber` and `TryGetIndex` methods so I can access values using this way.

```
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(memStr);
DynamicXMLObjectConverter converter = new DynamicXMLObjectConverter();
dynamic obj = converter.Deserialize(xmlReader, typeof(DynamicXMLObject));

string str = obj.dynamic_property;
string item = obj[0];
```

It works like a charm however I would like to access the same members through Runtime compiler services.

To get the member I use following code:

```
CallSiteBinder binder = Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, "dynamic_property", typeof(MyDynamic), new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) });
CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>> callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(binder);
var obj = callsite.Target(callsite, source);
```

It works and I can access any member of dynamic type.
The next thing for me is to get access to indexer using the same way.
I know that `Binder` supports `GetIndex` method so technically it should work in the same way as `GetMember` but it doesn't.

**Can someone help me and explain how I can access indexer using `callsite`?** Any code samples will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call Target correctly you would need to add one more CSharpArgumentInfo parameter to the Binder.GetIndex call. Otherwise it fails with ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Here is a working example:

```
var binder = Binder.GetIndex(CSharpBinderFlags.None, typeof (SampleDynamicObject), new[]
{
    CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
    CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null) // this argument is required!
});
var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(binder);
var obj = callsite.Target(callsite, sampleObject, 0); // 0 is an index
```

Comment: I was trying to pass only CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType argument but it seems both arguments need to be passed to get it work. It's a little bit strange behavior but it works in this way.